# java switch another piece of code, in another class

Tags: java, label, goto

I want to switch from a class to another class, like using labels.
in fact from a method

```
    static String GetTitle (Document document) throws IOException {

    return title;
}
```

in file functions.java and class functions

i want to switch to the main class, in the main file in a specific place... 
If it was in the same class i could use 
`label:` to the part i want to switch to,

and `break label;` where i want to leave the normal flow of the code...
but now i get an error that the label is not recognised (`not even MainClass.label;` is working). Any ideas?

Comment: The short answer is: you can't.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i don't understand anything of your problem...

Comment: Java does not support the GOTO construct, so whatever you are doing will probably not work as stated... If you are talking about some kind of SWITCH statement, please specify that... your question needs clarification.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Labels should only be used in a structured way when continuing / breaking in loops.

If you want to switch context from one class to another, you should probably simply **call a method** on an object of the other class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't; this is intentional.
Being able to jump from one class to another makes it hard to understand the execution paths in your code. Also, to what instance of the class would you jump?

Instead, determine how the control flow of your code should go. Probably, you want to do something after the switch. You may want to end your method upon leaving the switch, and let the caller of the method determine what to do based upon what your method returns.

Comment: hmm thanks i will check the flow again so i will create a method with the point i wan to go, and do it that way...